# c# deleting the 0s of an int, but not if it is 20

Tags: c#, string

In my string `start` can be all sorts of numbers (1 until 99), but when the numbers get generated, `1` always get shown like `01`. Is there an way to remove that `0`, without if the number is `20` that the number get changed to `2`?

Comment: Pick a language. Stick it with it for the duration of the question, at least.

Comment: How would we know why 0 is displayed in front of number without seeing your code? Can you share your code?

Comment: "but when the numbers get generated," this is the crucial part. Please post this code.

Comment: Just remove the first digit if it's a `0`, or, better still, change your formatter so the leading `0` is not generated.

Comment: You question is not very clear. Post a code sample of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @AditiRawat it is C#, but it said to me to use those tags, I will remove c++!

Comment: I guess it would be better to avoid that the `0` sneaks inside your string in the first place than removing it afterwards. You need to post the code where the number is generated and becomes the string!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`String.TrimStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string num = "0001";
num = num.TrimStart('0');
```

Comment: Well C# really does have everything. Have an upvote.

Comment: This code doesn't do what you think it does.  `TrimStart` returns a new string.  It does not alter the string in place.  You should assign the return value back to the string.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway fixed the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
if (start.ElementAt(0) == '0')
    start = start.Remove(0, 1);
```

or shorter:

```
start = start.ElementAt(0) == '0' ? start.Substring(1) : start;
```